# TYPO3 News Search with multiple words

Tags: search, typo3

I use TYPO3 7.6.1 AND News system 4.3.0

I have a page for search and i use the  "form search" and "search result" of plugin "News System".

I have some articles and one article has the title like this: "Min. Lavoro: Circ. n. 42"

If i search

> "circ"

the plugin "search results" show the article.

If i search

> "circ 42"

the plugin doesn't show the article in the results

How can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, because it searches for exactly this string you are submitted.

If you search for `circ. n. 42`, you will get a result.

In the code it uses the SQL LIKE `"%{searchString}%"`.

Comment: I opened an issue at https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/389 to make this feature happening